# Enable "low resolution" mode in Mac app bundle by default

Tags: macos, app-bundle, info-plist

I'm publishing a Mac app which supports Retina (high resolution) mode, but I would like to disable this mode by default. In other words, I want the "Open in Low Resolution" option in the Get Info menu of the app bundle to be checked when the app bundle is unzipped.

[image]

If the user wishes to enable high resolution mode, they should be able to uncheck the option.

In my attempt to solve this problem, I found the options `NSHighResolutionCapable` and `NSHighResolutionMagnifyAllowed` from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Explained/Explained.html. By playing with these properties in my `Info.plist` file, I can only manage to make the the option unchecked by default (high resolution by default), or completely disable high resolution (option is grayed-out).

I'm testing in MacOS Mojave 10.14.3.

Comment: If your app is high-resolution-aware, why don't you just render at lower resolutions by default and have an in-app preference setting to render at full resolution? What exactly are you trying to achieve by having it default to low resolution that you can't achieve yourself?

Comment: I have a GLFW + OpenGL app, and performance is abysmal with Retina laptops (Mojave seems to intentionally handicap OpenGL to promote Metal), but it works great in Low Resolution mode. I believe it's possible to request a non-Retina framebuffer from GLFW, but it's not immediately behaving correctly, so it seemed it would be simple to use Apple's "Open in Low Resolution" feature by default.